# Pandas DF to Xarray Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

Hi so initially I had Xarray dataset as follows:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 721, longitude: 1400, time: 71)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-12-31 2001-12-31 ... 2018-12-31
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -22.5 -21.75 -21.0 -20.25 ... 43.5 44.25 45.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 72.0 71.25 70.5 69.75 ... 28.5 27.75 27.0
Data variables:
    tas      (time, latitude, longitude) float64 5.033e+05 ... 1.908e+05
```

Now I converted it into dataframe and used groupby function on `latitude and longitude` to get `tas` value across all time dimension, and this was the sample df which will have `1038239 records(721 * 1440)` and tas will have array of `71 values(71 time)`:

```
latitude    longitude   tas
-90.0        358.75     [50603.53125, 50002.609375, 50183.98828125, 49...
-90.0        359.00     [50603.53125, 50002.609375, 50183.98828125, 49...
-90.0        359.25     [50603.53125, 50002.609375, 50183.98828125, 49...
-90.0        359.50     [50603.53125, 50002.609375, 50183.98828125, 49...
-90.0        359.75     [50603.53125, 50002.609375, 50183.98828125, 49...
```

Now I have performed some operation and created new column `tas_new` with similar size of `tas`. Now I want to create new dataset or add this variable in old dataset with same dimension `(time, latitude, longitude)`. But I'm not able to reshape it back to old one.

I tried getting all values from `tas_new` and stack them up like this:

```
array_tuple = (df_groups['trend'].values)
arrays = np.vstack(array_tuple)
```

This does return me array of shape `(1038239, 71)`. Can someone guide me how can I get back the original shape and add that variable to xarray dataset or create new one.

Expected Result:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 721, longitude: 1400, time: 71)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-12-31 2001-12-31 ... 2018-12-31
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -22.5 -21.75 -21.0 -20.25 ... 43.5 44.25 45.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 72.0 71.25 70.5 69.75 ... 28.5 27.75 27.0
Data variables:
    tas      (time, latitude, longitude) float64 5.033e+05 ... 1.908e+05
    tas_new  (time, latitude, longitude) float64 5.033e+05 ... 1.908e+05
```

Or array of dimension `(time, latitude, longitude)` from dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So once I had the, `arrays = np.vstack(array_tuple)` I converted them into the list as whole with shape `(1038239*71)` and then added that original dataframe corresponding to it's lat-lon-time pair. And then converted the whole dataframe to back to xarray.

PS: So the dataframe was pretty huge to convert into xarray for low memory(<12GB) system, so I broke the dataframe into 7 parts converted each of them into xarray and then concatenated them to get full Xarray dataset.